# Wired network not working in Ubuntu 18.04 - "Activation of network connection failed"

Tags: networking

i have a Dell E6540 laptop with dual boot (Ubuntu18.04/Windows10).

Ubuntu's wired network does not work, it is in connecting state and then it fails with the following error:

```
"Activation of network connection failed"
```

The only thing that seems to fix this is if i go to BIOS between switching from Win to Linux and change the "Wake On Lan" setting.

Is there a better fix for the issue? I have disabled fast boot from Windows.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Does this also happen after a cold boot straight into Ubuntu instead of a warm boot switching from Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: What passes as a "cold boot"?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: Cold Boot = Turn off power, start Ubuntu; Warm boot: reboot from Windows to Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi,
a cold boot improves things. Sometimes after a cold boot network also fails but then it is possible to restart it from Linux.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and provide a ˘dmesg | grep --ignore-case net` when it doesn"t work? (are we talking 1 in 10 or 1 in 100 cold boots?